# AndroidManifest.xml; unable to include external library

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm following the [MapView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) tutorial on the Android website

```
[2010-08-22 11:12:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestParser] Parser exception for /MeCercana/AndroidManifest.xml: Open quote is expected for attribute "android:name" associated with an  element type  "uses-library".
[2010-08-22 11:12:24 - MeCercana] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
```

I've copied in the external Maps API as instructed, my XML file looks as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.jameselsey"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">   
       <uses-library android:name=”com.google.android.maps” />          
        <activity android:name=".Mecercana"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

However, when I try to compile and run I get the following error

I'm unable to see what is wrong with my XML?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<uses-library android:name=”com.google.android.maps” />`

When you copied and pasted, the quote got turned into a different ascii value quote character. Retype the quote characters