# Error with <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I'm trying to develop an app using google maps, but don't know why it still gives me the error, I recheck my manifest file all seems to be ok. here is the manifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.interstars"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.interstars.InterMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      </application>
       </manifest>
```

**Error**

```
2 08:47:06 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for C:\Users\uchman\Documents\Work place\InterStars\AndroidManifest.xml: Attribute name "uses-library" associated with an element type "application" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

What sort of thing I missing? I'm still a beginner in android programming.

Comment: please see thi link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541061/androidmanifest-xml-unable-to-include-external-library

Comment: tried it, but it didn't work

Comment: if any add library like android-support-v4?

Comment: didn't add such library.. should i ? what is its function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks for all your help.. 
After stressing myself too much, i decieded to use GoogleMaps API V2. And thanks to the tutorials in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/ i was able to fix google maps to my app.
 P.S  GoogleMaps API V2 is much easier for both the user and programmer And no need for the uses-library. All that is required is the Google Play lib..

Answer (score 4):

try put

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

this line after all activity tags and before the end of application Tag

Comment: i actually tried doing as you said but still no change.. and i noticed my R.java is missing

Comment: there is an error in AndroidManifest.XMl so you will not be able to build your project so that R.java is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

The Target of your code must be set on Google API and not Android API.
Your project folder --> properties --> android --> In the project build target select the Google API for your API level.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work... i just even noticed that even when i delete totally the uses-library line, it gives me the same error about the uses-library.. Am so stressed!

Comment: @user1971741 try to update sdk and other tools, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not Sure but i have faced Same error Once i have started mapview.
the Way i got work around is as below:

if you have copy and paste below line

`<uses-library android:name=”com.google.android.maps” />`

then  the quote("") got turned into a different ASCII VALUE quote character.

You Should Retype the quote characters.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541061/androidmanifest-xml-unable-to-include-external-library)

Comment: he tried, and its already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541061/androidmanifest-xml-unable-to-include-external-library)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

- Right click your projects and click "Android Tools"
- Click "Add support Library" and directly add the library

Afterward run this.

Comment: thanks. helped reduce the error a little bit... but still giving the uses-library error..